# Meaning of "repay" in "the book repays close study"

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context

What does the word "repay" in essence mean in the phrase "the book repays close study"?

My OED defines "repay"  as

> to make return for; requite [a service, action, etc.]...
>   must repay their kindness

Which is clear as a bell to me. However, the context that doesn't seem to go home is what it means to "requite" or "make return for" close study.

The Oxford's definitions for *close* and *study* that seem plausible to me are these:

> **close**:
>   1. concentrated, searching, e.g. "close examination"; "close attention".
>   2. Leaving no gaps or weaknesses, rigorous [strict, severe], e.g. "close reasoning".
>   **study**:
>   1. the devotion of time and attention to acquiring information or knowledge, esp. from books.
>   2. the portrayal in literature or another art form of an aspect of behaviour or character etc.

To my mind, sense # 1 seems to win out and should fit for both words.

Yet, what does it mean to say that something "requites" or "pays back" thorough devotion/dedication/examination/research/inspection?

Does it by any means mean studying the book in question yields good results... pays off?

Comment: It means the knowledge you gain from studying a book in detail will offset the effort of studying a book in detail.

Comment: "Offset" is most apt. Thanks. I got the idea. In fact, as evident in my closing lines, I had thought as much as that.

Comment: Cool. Though *offset* may be a little weak here, because the *value* of the knowledge gained through close study may be  equal *or greater than* the effort *spent* gaining it. In re your final sentences, I'd say a closer idiom than *pay **off*** is *pay **back*** (sometimes with interest). The idiom "pay off" smacks too much of a risk or gamble for this context; the.author is offering a *guarantee*.

Comment: Please try to quote the complete sentence. If possible, also include the broader context. Provide a link to the source if it is available online.

Comment: @Dan Right again, and believe it or not, that's what I had had in mind at the time you wrote that...that the results to the efforts put in would be greater in value than the efforts themselves, you just beat me to the punch, taking the words outta my mouth...

Comment: And I do concur that pay back is the most apt usage...:) and also the implication of "pay off" with an underlying risk...

Comment: seems credible enough.

Comment: @Kris As it happens, "the book repays close study" by itself is the whole context and the complete sentence. The source is my OED, where I found it as an example for the usage of the word "repay" at its entry. Notwithstanding,  the meaning of the sentence is now evident to me, as plain as the nose on their faces, lol...

Comment: *noses on their faces*
The implied meaning to the sentence is that the book has us reap the wealth of knowledge on the account of the labor sown  into its study; reading it attentively and thoroughly.

Comment: The knowledge gained from the book is the fruit of all your labour that has gone into hovering over its pages...

Comment: And completely grasping all the material on them all.

Comment: Blooper: read "on the account of" as "on account of".

Comment: It's entirely a matter of opinion what metaphorical "currency" the book uses to compensate the close reader for his time and effort. He might well gain *knowledge*, but that's just one possibility. He might simply gain *enjoyment*, for example, or higher status within his literature-loving social circle. Regardless of all that, I think this is General Reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it's referring to effort. You'll expend some effort in studying the book, but the result is that you'll have less effort and/or more enjoyment in the future when you apply what you learned.

Comment: @Barmar: "Effort" is what the reader *gives/makes*. I'm just saying it's unspecified exactly what he *gets back in return*. I think being repaid in some kind of "negative future effort" (because you won't have to work so hard) is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Will someone please answer the question?

Comment: @ Fumble Fingers and Barmar: In essence, when a lot of care [effort plus attention] goes into studying the book, i.e. the doer makes a clean job of it rather than just go through the motions or cut corners: does it with much concentration, attention, thoroughness; it will yield benefits or good returns. Fumble Fingers opines that the benefits may be just about anything: knowledge, pleasure, delight, satisfaction, as the case may be. Fair enough.

Comment: Though, if you ask me, knowledge leads the field [or seems to pull a major lead ahead of the field, or extend its lead pretty ahead of the field] :-P

Comment: Barmar reckons one of the benefits the reader might reap is the knowledge gained and consequentially applied to a field of work thereupon would admit of less hard work. Point taken, though the validity of it still rests upon the case. Though both of these are subjective views, I give credence to them. Yet, the bare essence of it all is that you expend effort upon the book for as much return, regardless of what the return constitutes. I express my thanks to you both all the same, Fumble Fingers and Barmar.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist All the comments thus far show that the Q is essentially POB, that explains why there're no answers. See also comment by FumbleFingers above.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been clearer if they had said "rewards". That allows for a payback that is less or more than an equal payoff, and includes the less tangible benefits alluded to.

Answer (score 0):

My example sentence:

> The heading of [the book] has a very important purpose and repays careful study before we turn to [the rest the book content].

I hadn’t seen the word repays used in this manner. I’m thinking that it means it will be a very useful and rewarding effort to discuss how the heading gives insight into the entire book. (Much easier to say repays careful study).

Comment: I can't tell whether you're attempting to answer the original question with your own example or if you're asking a new question about this example.